# Where are caller-dependent fields defined in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I'm currently writing a POC GraphQL server. However the client UI needs fields that are transient (not part of the DB model), and formed or queried on the fly. For example: A `Post` can be liked, so I would like to put a flag `isLiked: Boolean` in graphQL. Depending on the caller this flag would be `true` if the `Post` is liked, or `false` if not. 
However this feels not right, as it is strictly speaking not part of the Post-type and is a form of UI-coupling (something we wanted to solve with GraphQL). Also I have the feeling there could be a better way that provides the `Like` as a type (as it also has a `date` for example). Would it be a good idea to have caller dependent fields defined in the type which are basically sub-queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphQL has some limitations, and I don't think it's wrong to add special-case fields to the schema to work around these limitations, particularly if they represent some query some actual application will make (and frequently).

Conversely, since a caller always specifies which specific fields they want out of an object, adding extra fields shouldn't really cost you anything in terms of performance or database queries.  So: do both!

```graphql
scalar DateTime
interface Node { id: ID! }
type Like implements Node {
  id: ID!
  post: Post!
  date: DateTime!
}
type Post implements Node {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  date: DateTime!
  likes: [Like!]!
  hasLike: Bool!
}
```

If you don't do this then the client's only choice is to query for specific like objects and pick some field out of them.  If you add limit-type parameters to the field you can minimize the cost, but it still feels a little awkward

```graphql
query PostSummary($id: ID!) {
  node(id: $id) {
    ... on Post {
      title
      date
      likes(limit: 1) { id }
    }
  }
}
```

If this is a real use case for your application, just adding the `hasLike` field seems like a more reasonable API, even if it's somewhat "specialized to the UI".

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David's answer, but just to offer a different perspective, there's something to be said for keeping user-specific fields out of types that otherwise are not. There's another alternative available, and that's to move such fields into the user or viewer query that already returns the data specific to the logged-in user. For example, you could have

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  likedPosts: [Post!]!
  # or better yet
  likedPostIds: [ID!]!
}
```

Of course, the downside to this approach is your client has to be "smart" enough to use the above to then derive whether the post was liked, which adds complexity on the front end.

The upside is, if you perform a logout or switch users, you only have to refetch the one query -- you don't have to blow away your entire cache because it's peppered with user-specific data that will now have to be refetched.

This kind of approach can also help performance. Any relational field, whether user-specific or not, will incur an additional cost. With this approach, your login query may be bloated and slower, but any subsequent queries will be that much faster. As your data grows, both in terms of breadth and depth, those performance gains can be significant.